# High power consumption from network driver Atheros Communications

Tags: 16.04, wireless, dell, power-management, battery

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS 15 9560.

Kernel:

Linux XPS 4.9.10-040910-generic #201702141931 SMP Wed Feb 15 00:33:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

In powertop it shows that two devices have very high power consumption. Everything is set to "good" in powertop.

11.9 W 100,0% USB device: usb-device-0cf3-e300

7.02 W 100,0% Radio device: ath10k_pci

Sometimes Radio Device goes down, but then the other is very high.
23.4 W 100,0% USB device: usb-device-0cf3-e300

The USB device in lsusb shows that it's from Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc.

Atheros Communications, Inc seems to make wireless drivers. The Radio Device ath10k is the upstream driver
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/atheros and https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k

Could it be a driver problem or something? Because I don't think it's reasonable power consumption numbers.

I beleive this is the Wireless card from sudo lspci -vvnn:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 136
Region 0: Memory at ed200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Address: fee00418  Data: 0000
    Masking: 000000fe  Pending: 00000000
Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
    DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
    DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
        MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
    DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
    LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
        ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
    LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via message
    DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
    LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
    LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
    UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
    CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
    AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
Capabilities: [148 v1] Virtual Channel
    Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
    Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
    Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
    Status: InProgress-
    VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
Capabilities: [168 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Capabilities: [178 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
    Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
Capabilities: [180 v1] L1 PM Substates
    L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
          PortCommonModeRestoreTime=50us PortTPowerOnTime=10us
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to measure power consumption of laptop components. What powertop tells you are just rough estimations. Often they are way off, as in your case. Please ignore them.

Comment: Oh okey thank you didn't know that, might be something else then.